# Linked Server already exists in sys.server

Tags: linked-server

I created Linked Server in ABC server and I can test the connection successfully to Destination server XYZ (Which is part of AOAG).
I created a Linked server from ABC --> XYZ .
I used AOAG Listener (AOAGListener) as server name while creating Linked server from ABC --> XYZ.

I am facing issue :

> Could not find server 'AOAGListener' in sys.servers.Verify that the
>   correct server name was specified.If necessary,execute the stored
>   procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add server to sys.servers.

Please help as I can see server name in sys.servers

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved.

Actually it was for some ETL process for which I need to access a server which is not in AOAG and a server which is part of AOAG.I have added the listener only in one remote server as Linked server but not AOAG servers.

> I have to add Listener as Linked server in each AOAG servers(Replicas) and the remote server which is a stand-alone
>   to make the ETL process work.

Hope this helps someone.